# Merge multiple dataframes - how to assign column names automatically?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have five dataframe. They all have two columns with names 'item' and 'price'. Each table represents prices of supermarket items for period 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I want to merge these tables such that I have a table that shows prices of each item for different period.

In the new table I want to columns to be named price_0, price_1, price_2 etc

Is there a way to achieve this using the pd.merge function?

Comment: show what you have tried please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have merged your columns, use this list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [f'Price_{idx}' for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with `pd.concat` -

1. First create a list of dfs
2. Enumerate over the list of dfs and set 'item' as index, and add suffix to 'price' using the enumerate
3. Next concatenate the list of dfs on index 'item' and reset the index.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]], columns=['item','price'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[4,6],[6,8]], columns=['item','price'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[4,4],[5,6],[6,8]], columns=['item','price'])

dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
dfs = [j.set_index('item').add_suffix('_'+str(i)) for i,j in enumerate(dfs)]
print(pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index())
```

```
   item  price_0  price_1  price_2
0     1      2.0      2.0      2.0
1     3      4.0      4.0      NaN
2     4      NaN      6.0      4.0
3     5      6.0      NaN      6.0
4     6      NaN      8.0      8.0
5     7      8.0      NaN      NaN
```

By default `pd.concat` does outer joins but you can set it to do inner joins by changint it to `pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='inner')`

Comment: Thanks - but what if the items in the dataframe are not necessarily the same? e.g. in df2 the items are 1, 2, 3, 5 instead of 1, 3, 5, 7 ?

Comment: You can simply change the above code and test the scenario :). I have still updated it for your reference.